# MNIST: plot first training image and save using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tensorflow

There is TensorFlow tutorial code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py) that goes over how to load MNIST images. I modified it slightly for my own usage.

My goal: plot the first MNIST training image and save it.

I am working on a remote system, and I can't get the display to work, so I just want to save the image without looking at it first.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
import argparse
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('pdf')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_data():
        #Import data, return training data
        mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)
        return mnist.train.images

if __name__ == '__main__':
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str, default="/tmp/mnist/data")
        FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
        x_data = get_data()
        #first training image is x_data[0], has shape (784,)
        first_image = x_data[0]
        first_image = np.array(first_image, dtype='float')
        pixels= first_image.reshape((28,28))

        mnist_fig = plt.figure()
        plt.plot(pixels)
        plt.imshow(pixels, cmap="gray")
        savefig_val = "first_image"
        mnist_fig.savefig(savefig_val+".pdf")
```

And here is the image that is produced:

[image]

Problems: I'm pretty sure that's supposed to be a clearly recognizable digit, and it isn't. It also shouldn't have colours across the top of the image.

Comment: This is what i would expect with that code (and looks okay; ignoring normalization stuff). The lines come from ```plot(pixels)```. What are you trying to achieve there? And in regards to *clearly recognizable*: just compare with the original one and you will see if it is or if you did for example mirror it.

Comment: Thanks @sascha. I just want to save a plot without looking at it first. There shouldn't be any coloured lines. How can I compare this to the original image? All I have is the file from the TensorFlow tutorial, and I'm trying to visualize the first image.

Comment: Then remove ```plt.plot(pixels)``` and probably use png instead of pdf. Also check out the specification of the set to learn how those are stored to make sure you are reading them correctly including the 1d-2d reshape which assumes an order. Or just do the same with other images until you find one which looks good and is not symmetric in regards to transposition (all but 0 i would think).